# converting series in data frame from exp. object to float

Tags: python, pandas

i have csv, and two columns of that csv is exponential notation.

I want to convert it to float or int, and doing this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('clm_data.csv', sep = ';')
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.0f}'.format)
df.dtypes
```

those types:

```
NAME             object
ID               object
RESPONSE_TYPE     int64
RESPONSE_DATE    object
SYSTEM.          object
```

func for transformation:

```
def unfloater(x):
    value = x.replace(',', '.')
    return float(value)
```

and when i try to use apply for multiple rows like:

```
df[["NAME", "RESPONSE_DATE"]] = df[["NAME", "RESPONSE_DATE"]].apply(unfloater)
```

i got TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

But when i use apply for one series - all works well.

What is wrong with multiple apply?
axis = 1 is useless

Comment: This circumvents your actual quesiton, but perhaps all you actually wanted was `df = pd.read_csv('clm_data.csv', sep = ';', decimal=",")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now passing a row to your function instead of a single value, so `float()` does not work.
You can use `.astype(float)` instead like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["1,1e1", "2,2e2", "3,3e3", "4,4e4"],
                   "b": ["5,5e5", "6,6e6", "7,7e7", "8,8e8"]})

df[["a", "b"]].apply(lambda row: row.str.replace(",", ".")).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following methods :

**Method 1: Use astype()**

```
df['NLS'] = df['NLS'].astype(float)
```

**Method 2: Use to_numeric() to Convert Object to Float**

```
df['NLS'] = pd.to_numeric(df['NLS'], errors='coerce')
```

to convert all

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
df.dtypes
```

Comment: the problem is how to apply function to multiple series, because my solution works well with only one of them as you suggested